# Добавление новой записи в таблицу при помощи запроса.

Tags: access

Как в access 2000 добавить новую запись или несколько записей в таблицу при помощи запроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из удобных способов такой.
Создаете запрос. В нем пишете примерно следующее:

```
INSERT INTO таблица ( Фамилия, Имя, Отчество, Серия_паспорта, Номер_паспорта)
VALUES (фамилия_, имя_, отчество_, серия_паспорта_, номер_паспорта_);
```

Тут в выражении `VALUES (...)` параметры, которые нужно заполнить при вызове запроса.
Сохраняем запрос. Даем ему имя, например, `ЗапросНаДобавление`.
Открываем `Visual Basic` и пишем команду:

```
Dim q As dao.QueryDef
Set q = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("ЗапросНаДобавление") 'имя хранимого запроса
'устанавливаем входящие параметры из полей для ввода на форме
q.Parameters("фамилия_").Value = StrConv(ПолеФамилия.Value, vbUpperCase)
q.Parameters("имя_").Value = StrConv(ПолеИмя.Value, vbUpperCase)
q.Parameters("отчество_").Value = StrConv(ПолеОтчество.Value, vbUpperCase)
q.Parameters("серия_паспорта_").Value = StrConv(ПолеСерия.Value, vbUpperCase)
q.Parameters("номер_паспорта_").Value = ПолеНомер.Value
'выполняем запрос \\ не действует для SELECT
q.Execute
'Обязательно закрываем
q.Close: Set q = Nothing
```

Как вы уже поняли, данные для заполнения берутся из полей для ввода на форме `Access` например, при нажатии на кнопку "*Сохранить*". А если надо несколько записей добавить, так это только циклом (несколько раз вызывать приведенный выше код). Только для большей скорости, закрыть соединение надо после выполнения ряда запросов на добавление.